# Scheme returns <#Closure> instead of 1

Tags: scheme

I have just start to pick up scheme and figuring out its ins and outs. I was trying to work out some practice problems and I came across this one. With my-counter defined, I thought calling my-counter would return 1, but instead it's returning <#Closure>. I understand to some extent what closures are and thought that count belongs to let, so it would return 1, but I supposed I overlooked something.

```
(define my-counter
  (let ((count 0))
      (lambda ()
        (set! count (+ count 1))
        count)))
```

Comment: This is a pretty complex idea that's only introduced halfway through [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-19.html#%_chap_3), after you're comfortable with procedure-producing procedures.

Answer (score 0):

`my-counter` returns a procedure. You need to call that procedure to get the next value.

```
(define counter-1 (my-counter))
(define counter-2 (my-counter))
(write (counter-1))
(write (counter-1))
(write (counter-2))
```